# What is the easiest way to query a CSV file in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

I have a fairly simple CSV file that I would like to use within a SQL query. I'm using Oracle SQL Developer but none of the solutions I have found on the web so far seem to have worked.  I don't need to store the data (unless I can use temp tables?) just to query it and show results.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an `EXTERNAL TABLE`. This essentially maps a CSV (or indeed any flat file) to a table. You can then use that table in queries. You will not be able to perform DML on the external table.

Comment: Thank you. I found some tutorials on this but it appears I don't have CREATE DIRECTORY privileges to define where my csv files are stored. Can I use an existing directory, if such a thing exists? I do appear to have CREATE TABLE privileges (these are just temp tables right? I can drop them at the end of my query?). Thanks

Comment: These are not temp tables. They will persist until you drop them; just like a regular heap table. If you do not have CREATE DIRECTORY priv, get you DBA to create a directory for you that you can then use.